# uninstall: Release not loaded: new: release: not found, chart deployed using helm 3

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have both helm 2 and helm 3 installed in my localhost. I have created a new chart using helm2

```
sanket@Admins-MacBook-Pro poc % helm create new
Creating new
```

created a chart 'new ' using helm version 2. Now I have deployed the chart using helm version 3

```
sanket@Admins-MacBook-Pro poc % helm3 install new new --namespace test 
NAME: new
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Apr 23 17:56:03 2020
NAMESPACE: test
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace test -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=new,app.kubernetes.io/instance=new" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80
```

Now when I try to delete the 'new' release it shows :-

```
sanket@Admins-MacBook-Pro poc % helm3 delete new 
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: new: release: not found
```

any idea how to resolve this issue .

Comment: Can you see the release if you run ```helm3 ls```?

Comment: figured out this, need to pass --namespace also

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Need to pass `--namespace` with the delete command.

```
helm3 ls --namespace test
helm3 ls --namespace deployment_name
```

Answer (score 85):

By default, **helm3** only shows releases of **default** namespace.
Do the following to get your release and delete it.

```bash
# Get all releases
helm ls --all-namespaces
# OR
helm ls -A

# Delete release
helm uninstall release_name -n release_namespace
```

Comment: Thanks so much, took me way too long to find this.

Comment: was in the wrong namespace

Answer (score 2):

**You can check your all helm release and charts**

*1. All helm release*

```
helm ls -A
```

*2. Helm release in specific namespace*

```
helm ls -n {releaseNameSpace}
```

**And if it is there**

*1. Helm uninstall*

```
helm uninstall {releaseName} -n {releaseNameSpace}
```